# How to avoid implicit mailto link in Restructured Text?

Tags: restructuredtext

I'm new to Restructured Text and am trying to write a document that refers to a project with an "at" sign in the name, something like "Foo@BAR". When I convert the .rst file into HTML using the docutils "rst2html" tool, this is converted into a "mailto" link. If I use double backticks for verbatim rendering, it is turned into monospace text. How can I get it to be rendered in the normal text font, and not converted into a link?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [character escaping](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#escaping) to include an `@` within a word. In reStructuredText the escape character is `\`, so try using `Foo\@BAR` in your document.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I got to stuck on the idea of escaping the entire string rather than just the @ character.